# ¿Como solucionar error en evento onchange? Para filtrar ciudades/provincias desde el controlador

Tags: javascript, html, c#

Estoy desarrollando un filtro en javascript y c#, para filtrar provincias y ciudades al elegir un país en específico.

Luego en las provincias filtrar sus respectivas ciudades, se que hay varias soluciones ya probadas, pero quería consultar ya que siento que no voy a encontrar donde esta la falla...

El error que me tira al debugear en el navegador es :

> Uncaught TypeError: ProvinciasID is not a function
>       at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (Create:383)

```js
            function ProvinciasID() {
                var id = ($('#ProvinciasID').val().length == 0) ? "0" : $('#ProvinciasID :selected').val();
                var paises = ($('#PaisesID').val().length == 0) ? "0" : $('#PaisesID :selected').val();
                window.location.href = "/Empresas/Create/" + id + '?c=' + paises;
            };
```

```html
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="PaisIdFk" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"></label>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <select class="form-control" id="PaisesID" onchange="ProvinciasID()" asp-items="ViewBag.Paises"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ProvinciaIdFk" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"></label>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <select class="form-control" id="ProvinciasID" onchange="ProvinciasID()" asp-items="ViewBag.Provincias"></select>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="LocalidadIdFk" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"></label>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <select asp-for="LocalidadIdFk" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Localidades"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Luego en el controlador hago lo necesario para filtrar con este código C#, recibiendo en el método de la vista los parámetros int: C e Id... devuelvo los viewdata llenos, pero no me funciona

Edito para agregar el método en el controlador, así tener mas noción del problema completo y disculpas si no lo hice antes:

```
    public IActionResult Create(int? id, int? c)
    {
        CrearEmpresaViewModel crearEmpresaViewModel = _empresas.CrearEmpresa(id, c, out IEnumerable<Pais> paises, out IEnumerable<Provincia> provincias, out IEnumerable<Ciudad> ciudades);
        ViewData["EmpresaARTIdFk"] = new SelectList(crearEmpresaViewModel.EmpresaARTs.OrderBy(r => r.Nombre), "EmpresaARTId", "Nombre");


        ViewData["Paises"] = new SelectList(paises.OrderBy(r => r.Nombre), "PaisId", "Nombre", c);
        if (provincias != null)
            ViewData["Provincias"] = new SelectList(provincias.OrderBy(r => r.Nombre), "ProvinciaId", "Nombre", id);
        else
        {
            var sinProvincias = new List<Provincia>();
            sinProvincias.Add(new Provincia { Nombre = "SIN DATOS" });
            ViewData["Provincias"] = new SelectList(sinProvincias, "ProvinciaId", "Nombre", id);
        }
        ViewData["Localidades"] = new SelectList(ciudades.OrderBy(r => r.Nombre), "CiudadId", "Nombre");

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: El porqué de que el editor de código te tira ese error es porque donde pusiste tu código javascript no es necesario abrir etiquetas <script>

Comment: Para lo que quieres hacer es mejor utilizar **jQuery**. Te recomiendo leas este artículo [Cómo crear un Cascading DropDownList en ASP.NET MVC](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2019/11/24/c%C3%B3mo-crear-un-cascading-dropdownlist-en-aspnet-mvc)

Comment: En realidad no se de que version heredad JQuery,, porque ahora no estoy usando nada.. pero ese mismo script, heredando de la version correcta ya andaria ? y cual seria esa version ?

Comment: @FernandoTorres osea que si va en medio del body yo no necesito declarar Script ? o deberia ir abajo ?

Comment: @FernandoTorres he quitado las etiquetas script pero no compila

Comment: Hola, amigo, podrías refrescarme un poco lo que hay que hacer para explicarte y darte una solución?

Comment: Hola! @FernandoTorres, necesito filtrar las ciudades de acuerdo a la provincia elegida, para eso dispongo de 3 selects en una vista, e intento con ese metodo JS que se ve al principio llevar las ID hacia el controlador donde yo ( ya debuguee y anda perfecto ) devuelvo los viewdata llenos con ciudades y provincias respectivamente, ahora amplio mi respuesta para que se vea la logica en el controller.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el código javascript completo? Parece que esa función está definida en un ámbito al que no alcanza tu código. He intentado reproducir tu problema en el siguiente repositorio de github: https://github.com/ojgarciab/stackoverflow-323012 [(ejecutar en gitpod)](https://gitpod.io/#https://github.com/ojgarciab/stackoverflow-323012)

Comment: Tienes razón,me traicionó mi falta de costumbre (siempre uso addeventlistener). Borro mi comentario para evitar errores

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El error está en que se esta redeclarando la variable `ProvinciasID`, dado que estás usando esta palabra tanto para nombrar el `id` de un Elemento del DOM, como para una función en javascript.

Cambia el nombre de la función y asegúrate de declararla entre etiquetas `<script></script>` antes del cierre del `</body>`.

## DOM ( DOCUMENT OBJECT MODEL )

Cuando en el DOM se asigna un `id` a un elemento, éste automáticamente se convierte en una variable global en javascript, o sea, son OBJECTOS que se pueden acceder por javascript.

> El error no es muy común porque el navegador logra identificar cuando son función y cuando objecto, para este caso `<select>` el API `HTMLSelectElement` no cuenta con el evento `onchange` en DOM de Gecko, que es accesible solo por `Element` de `ElementHTML` es la especificación **DOM LEVEL 3** de la **W3C**. Lee https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/

## Como hacerlo:

Para lograr tu cometido asumiendo que la información en el lado del servidor llega bien, seria agregar el evento de cambio sobre el `<select id="pais">` solamente, y en el de `pais` hacer que el `provincia` quede vació.

```js
$("#js_pais").on('change',function(){
  // para obter el id del pais
  let pais_select = this.value
  $("#js_provincia")
  .find('option[pais]') // busca solo input con atributo pais
  .each(function(index,element){ 
      $element = $(element)
      if( $element.attr('pais') === pais_select ){
        $element.show() // muestra el input
      } else{
        $element.hide() // si no lo oculta
      }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="js_pais">
  <option value="0">SELECCIONE PAIS</option>
  <option value="1">ESPAÑA</option>
  <option value="2">COLOMBIA</option>
</select>

<select id="js_provincia">
  <option value="0">SELECCIONE PROVINCIA</option>
  <option value="1" pais="1">PROVINCIA 1</option>
  <option value="1" pais="1">PROVINCIA 2</option>
  <option value="1" pais="2">PROVINCIA 3</option>
  <option value="1" pais="2">PROVINCIA 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Este comportamiento sólo se produce cuando no existe previamente dicha variable. Si creas una función a posteriori con el mismo nombre, se crea una variable homónima que sobreescribe a la se que ha creado mediante este comportamiento.

Comment: Correcto @OscarGarcia, por eso la mejor solución es cambiar el nombre de la función, probablemente en alguna parte del codigo (que no publico) esta re-definiendo función.

Comment: Este mensaje no saldría si se está redefiniendo la variable como función. Es probable que, simplemente, se está definiendo (como indiqué en mi comentario) fuera del ámbito global. También es probable que él haya creado una variable global con el mismo nombre tras la definición de la función pero, como dije, hasta que no comparta el código javascript completo no se puede saber qué está ocurriendo, sólo puedes elucubrar, y para eso es mejor usar los comentarios.

Comment: Ahora les paso el código completo de la vista, porque creo que no hay ningún otro script en la misma vista que utiliza ese nombre, pero por las dudas mejor verificar, gracias por tomarse su tiempo a los dos y ojala me ayude a solucionar!

Comment: HOLA!!! mil disculpas mi demora, sali de vacaciones! efectivamente el nombre era el mismo de la variable y eso daba error, ahora lo cambie y funciona perfectamente todo el combo! mil gracias!!! no se como entregarte mas recompensa, creo que paso el tiempo limite pero te daria mis 50 ! mil gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Yo no programar en .net pero a lo mejor te es útil un código que ya utilizo y me muestra unos comboxselectores en cascada 2 niveles.

Primero cargo el primer select, en este caso me muestra una lista de 38 opciones, para que esto funcione debes cargar el id y el valor de ese id, es decir por ejemplo 1 y este corresponde a Argentina, 2 a Brasil y así sucesivamente...esto desde la base de datos haces tu consulta y muestras o imprimes:
Aquí va tu consulta...(en lenguaje que utilizas)

y aqui se imprime en pantalla...y pasas los valores o parámetros

```
echo '<option style="font-size:10px;" style="width:100px;" value="'.$cadenaCCT.'">'.$listaUnidades.'</option>';
```

Cada que seleccionas una de las opciones con la siguiente función captura el id o valor

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#Unidades").on('change', function () {
    $("#Unidades option:selected").each(function () {
        var cadenaCCT = $(this).val();

        $.post("buscarPersonal.php", { cadenaCCT: cadenaCCT }, function(data) {

            $("#Personal").html(data);
        });         
    });
```

});
});

y eso lo manda a una consulta que regresa el segundo valor de tu select dinamica
en mi caso despliega nombre del personal adscrito a cada unidad laboral

Aquí va tu consulta...(en lenguaje que utilizas)

y aqui se imprime en pantalla...

```
echo '<option style="font-size:10px;" style="width:100px;" value="'.$Numero_Empleado.'">'.$Nombre.'</option>';}
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta! voy a tener en cuenta el on(change) que nunca suelo usar...

Comment: De nada BelgratoSystem, me costo algo de trabajo llegar a esta solucion, investigando en varios lugares, y al final logre que me funcione sin problema, si ya de por si los combox selectores son un dolor de cabeza si son cargados desde la BD, creo que cualquier ayuda que se pueda ofrecer sera buena.  Saludos