# Quitar onchange del html con javascript

Tags: javascript, woocommerce

Estoy modificando un formulario de woocommerce, por el cual a través de unos select, voy mostrando los países de los correspondientes Continentes. Es decir cuando hago click en Europa del desplegable salen: España, Francia, Alemania, etc.

Bien, el problema está en que en woocommerce no puedo añadir **onChange="ponPaises(this.form)"**
por lo cual no funciona el código, mi pregunta es .
**¿ cómo podria detectar esos clicks fuera del formulario? es decir, que sea desde javascript ?**

¡ Muchísimas gracias por vuestra ayuda !

un cordial saludo,

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Formulario</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="ejercicios con javascript que permite obtener datos de los paises de centroamerica"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="ejercicio_paises, javascript, html, css"/>

</head>
<body>

    <script>
    var paises = new Array()
    paises[1] = ["Elige país","España","Portugal","Alemania", "Francia","Reino Unido (UK)"]
    paises[2] = ["Elige país","Argentina","Colombia","Perú"]
    paises[3] = ["Elige país","México"]
    paises[4] = ["Elige país","Miami"]


    function ponPaises(formu)
    {   var elConti = formu.region.selectedIndex
        formu.pais.length = paises[elConti].length
        for (i=0; i<formu.pais.length; i++)
        {   formu.pais.options[i].text = paises[elConti][i]
        }
    }
    function ponProvincias(formu)
    {   var elConti = formu.region.selectedIndex
        var elPais = formu.pais.selectedIndex
        formu.provincia.length = provincias[elConti][elPais].length
        for (i=0; i<formu.provincia.length; i++)
        {   formu.provincia.options[i].text = provincias[elConti][elPais][i]
        }
    }
    </script>
<form>
<select name="region" onChange="ponPaises(this.form)">
<option selected>Región</option>
<option>Europa</option>
<option>Latinoamérica</option>
<option>América Central</option>
<option>Estados Unidos</option>
</select>
<select name="pais" onChange="ponProvincias(this.form)">
<option></option>
</select>

</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Me llama la atención tu array, la comienzas en 1 cuando la cuenta empieza en 0, entonces tu primer elemento es el segundo, aparte es preferible que uses [`.push()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)

Comment: @NicolasOñate funcionar , me funciona el código así. Lo unico que necesito es quitar onchange del select del html, porque no soy capaz de añadirlo en el formulario de woocommerce. ¿cómo podria hacerlo? gracias por la ayuda :)

Comment: @NicolasOñate algo encontré: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/323012/como-solucionar-error-en-evento-onchange-para-filtrar-ciudades-provincias-desd?rq=1

Comment: En la respuesta está usando JQuery, comprueba si lo tienes y si es así con `$(#idSelect).change(function(){//Lo que quieras hacer});` tendrías solucionado tu problema

Comment: @NicolasOñate , puedo usar jquery, lo que pasa que con el enlace que te he pasado, tengo el siguiente problema, y esque  en la opcion : <option value="1" pais="1">  . Trae el tag pais,  y ese tag no lo puedo meter, solo podria compararlo con el value de cada pais.

Comment: Para escuchar los eventos del `select` lo más simple sería asignarle un `id` y escuchar los `on.change` por ese id. Si fuera tu, organizaría algo así como un JSON con la lista de países por continente, así buscaría en el JSON la lista de países según el continente seleccionado que es lo que quieres según he leído. No entiendo por qué los tienes separados bajo los índices `1, 2, 3, 4` ¿? No se corresponde con lo que planteas en la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siempre es buena práctica trabajar los elementos con ID, sin embargo, [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) permite acceder por atributo y valor, que es todo lo que se necesita; en este caso `[name=region]` y `[name=pais]`

No me agrada la forma en que creas el arreglo, pero no representa un problema en sí mismo, así que lo dejé como lo tienes. Además, desactivé el select *pais* hasta que se haya seleccionado una región válida:

```js
var paises = new Array();
paises[1] = ["Elige país","España","Portugal","Alemania", "Francia","Reino Unido (UK)"];
paises[2] = ["Elige país","Argentina","Colombia","Perú"];
paises[3] = ["Elige país","México"];
paises[4] = ["Elige país","Miami"];

// Obtener select región
let region = document.querySelector('[name=region]');
// Obtener select país
let pais = document.querySelector('[name=pais]');
// Asignar evento onchange
region.addEventListener('change', function() {
    // Borrar todos los elementos de país, hay que comenzar desde el último
    for(let i = pais.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
        pais.remove(i);
    }
    // Desactivar hasta ver que tiene valores
    pais.disabled = true;
    let value = region.selectedIndex;
    // Solo si hay una selección válida
    if(value != 0) {
        // Obtener opciones
        let opciones = paises[value];
        opciones.forEach(opc => {
            // Crear opción, asignar valor y texto
            let opcion = document.createElement('option');
            opcion.text = opc;
            // Agregar opción al select
            pais.appendChild(opcion);
        });
        // Activar select
        pais.disabled = false;
    }
    // Obtener valor actual (texto)
    console.log(region.value);
});

// Asignar evento al select país, aunque no especificaste para qué lo quieres
pais.addEventListener('change', function() {
    console.log(`País seleccionado: ${pais.value}`);
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Formulario</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="ejercicios con javascript que permite obtener datos de los paises de centroamerica"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="ejercicio_paises, javascript, html, css"/>

</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="region">
<option selected>Región</option>
<option>Europa</option>
<option>Latinoamérica</option>
<option>América Central</option>
<option>Estados Unidos</option>
</select>
<select name="pais" disabled>
<option></option>
</select>

</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Tienes un buen lío ahi montado.
Lo primero que veo es que te cuesta comprender el funcionamiento de una array, imagina que es un armario con cajones infinitos, dentro de el vas guardando cosas, como es en este caso paises:

```
var paises = new Array()
paises.push(["Elige país","España","Portugal","Alemania", "Francia","Reino Unido (UK)"]);
paises.push(["Elige país","Argentina","Colombia","Perú"]);
paises.push(["Elige país","México"]);
paises.push(["Elige país","Thailandia, Japón, India"]);
```

usando [`.push()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) insertas en la primera balda disponible, es decir, si en ese *armario* no hay nada, lo pondra en el primer hueco, el siguiente en el segundo y así sucesivamente, **las arrays el primer número es el 0** entonces, en tu código lo estabas colocando en el segundo hueco.

El siguiente punto, los scripts suele ir en la ultima parte de body, ya que te puede causar problemas como el que tienes.

Como en los comentarios has puesto que si puedes usar jquery y que te estabas mirando una pregunta con el he creado el siguiente código que hace lo que tu deseas:

```js
var paises = new Array()
    paises.push(["Elige país","España","Portugal","Alemania", "Francia","Reino Unido (UK)"]);
    paises.push(["Elige país","Argentina","Colombia","Perú"]);
    paises.push(["Elige país","México"]);
    paises.push(["Elige país","Thailandia", "Japón", "India"]);

$('#region').change(function(){
    var seleccionado = $('#region').val();
  
  switch(seleccionado){
    case "1":
        var opciones = crearOptions(paises[0]);
      $('#pais option').remove();
        $('#pais').html(opciones);
    break;
    case "2":
      var opciones = crearOptions(paises[1]);
      $('#pais option').remove();
        $('#pais').html(opciones);
    break;
    case "3":
      var opciones = crearOptions(paises[2]);
      $('#pais option').remove();
        $('#pais').html(opciones);
    break;
    case "4":
      var opciones = crearOptions(paises[3]);
      $('#pais option').remove();
        $('#pais').html(opciones);
    break;
  }
});

function crearOptions(obj){
    var html = "";
  $.each(obj, function(item,value){
    html += '<option value ="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>'
  });
  return html;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="region">
<option selected>Región</option>
<option value="1">Europa</option>
<option value="2">Latinoamérica</option>
<option value="3">América Central</option>
<option value="4">Asia</option>
</select>
<select id="pais">
</select>
```

He cambiado Estados unidos ya que es un país y no una región (Ya que estamos corrigiendo XD)

Comment: gracias! me da error a la hora de añadirlo en wordpress  $ is not a function
    at (index):508, concretamente en : $('#region').change(function(){  "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function " , sin subirlo me funciona bien, pero en wordpress no me funciona. El anterior codigo que puse si me funcionaba, pero iba algo mal. Encontré esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343714/typeerror-is-not-a-function-when-calling-jquery-function

Comment: osea, por lo que veo en wordpress hay que ponerlo de otra forma para que funcione correctamente el jquery -_-"

Comment: ya lo conseguí ! gracias Nicolas  y Triby :D

Comment: Me alegro que lo lograses, si te ha servido mi respuesta o la de Tribi, marques como correcta una de las dos, en caso de que no haya tenido nada que ver te animo a escribir una respuesta con lo que has hecho para lograr solucionarlo.

Comment: cierto, se me olvidaba, no me deja marcar las dos a la vez -_-" gracias